# NULL exception for drawerlayout when adding recyclerview in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I am getting following error for DrawerLayout while adding RecyclerView in the same activity which has android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Here is my c# code

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerLayout = this.FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
}
```

Here is my axml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/nav_view"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
      app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#e7e6e6"
            android:paddingTop="60dp">
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If I will remove following code from axml then it will work fine. I don't know why DrawerLayout become NULL when I am adding android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView in my xml file?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this first:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LayoutContainingDrawer);
```

before you try to find it:

```
drawerLayout = this.FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
```